# Не происходит переход в другой хэндлер после нажатия inline клавиатуры aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, клавиатура, inline

После нажатия на одну из кнопок инлайн клавиатуры никакого действия не происходит, на этой кнопке внизу справа появляются часики, которые стоят секунд 5, потом исчезают и все.
Вот мой код:

```
@dp.message_handler(state=FindBook.book)
async def looking_book(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    answer = message.text
    if len(answer) > 200:
        await message.answer('Максимально допустимое количество символов - 200. Попробуйте снова')
        await FindBook.book.set()
    else:
        await state.update_data(book=answer)
        await message.answer('Приступаю к поиску')
        data = await state.get_data()
        result = await find_book(answer=data["book"], message=message, bot=bot)
        if result:
            await state.update_data(next_page_url=result)
            await message.answer('Какое действие совершим?', reply_markup=choice)
        else:
            await message.answer('Книг больше нет')
            await state.reset_state()


@dp.callback_query_handler(text="next_page", state=FindBook.next_page)
async def new_page(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer('Приступаю к поиску')
    data = await state.get_data()
    result = await next_page(url=data["next_page_url"], message=message, bot=bot)
    if result:
        await state.update_data(next_page_url=result)
        await message.answer('Какое действие совершим?', reply_markup=choice)
    else:
        await message.answer('Книг больше нет')
        await state.reset_state()


@dp.callback_query_handler(text="cancel", state=FindBook.cancel)
async def cancel(call: CallbackQuery, message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await call.answer("Вы отменили текущую комманду")
    await call.message.edit_reply_markup()
    await state.reset_state()
    await message.answer('Для просмотра всего функционала, воспользуйтесь коммандой /help')
```

Клавиатура:

```
choice = InlineKeyboardMarkup(
                              inline_keyboard=[
                                  [
                                      InlineKeyboardButton(
                                          text="Следующая страница",
                                          callback_data="next_page"
                                      )
                                  ],
                                  [
                                      InlineKeyboardButton(
                                          text="Отмена",
                                          callback_data="cancel"
                                      )
                                  ]
                              ])
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Если кратко просто уберите .next_page и .cancel и он должен заработать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по коду, ни разу не увидел чтобы было изменение текущего стейта на FindBook.cancel или FindBook.next_page.

Получается вы на кнопку жмёте а Стейт все ещё остаётся на FindBook.book.

Чтобы ваш код заработал просто в колбеках хендлеров оставьте state=FindBook без уточнения какое именно состояние.

Comment: А он разве не должен переходить в хендлер по callback_data? К примеру для следующей страницы у кнопки callback_data="next_page", для хендлера я выставил параметр text="next_page" или это так не работает? Если стейты убрать, перехода в следующий хендлер не будет

Comment: Нет, то что в скобках после message_handler или callback_query_handler по факту является фильтрами. И если есть некий колбек от нажатия кнопками идёт проверка по этим фильтрам. В вашем случае получается что Стейт находится все ещё в состоянии book, и хендлер просто не срабатывает так как у них в фильтре другие стейты.

Comment: Понял! Благодарю вас за подробный ответ